# Why no copy methods for channels in IOUtils?

Tags: apache-commons-io

Can anybody please tell me why there is no `copy(Large)` methods, for channels, in [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) class?

Are those functionalities implemented in any other class? Or is it unnecessary?

Or is it just that those methods are not defined yet?

I'm not particularly a fan of 3rd party utilities and, consequently, using another library, such as [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), is not an option.

Moreover, I'm asking about the functionalities just because Commons-IO is, transitively, on my classpath.

```java
static long copy1(ReadableByteChannel source, WritableByteChannel target,
                  ByteBuffer buffer) {
    long count = 0L;
    while (source.read(buffer) != -1) {
        for (buffer.flip(); buffer.hasRemaining();) {
            count += target.write(buffer);
        }
        buffer.clear();
    }
    return count;
}

static long copy2(ReadableByteChannel source, WritableByteChannel target,
                  ByteBuffer buffer) {
    long count = 0L;
    while (source.read(buffer) != -1) {
        buffer.flip();
        count += target.write(buffer);
        buffer.compact();
    }
    for (buffer.flip(); buffer.hasRemaining(); ) {
        target.write(buffer);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Because nobody uses channels :-) I've never seen NIO somewhere in a general purpose software, where the usage of Apache commons would make sense. If I am developing a high performance I/O library or an application server, I would not rely on third party library.